# Does nutch generator use CrawlDB to for initial links?

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I know that inital seeds are provided by a flat file. However, where are these urls injected into? Is it crawlDB? And if that is the case, are the new links, fetched by the crawler, stored back into crawlDB? and what happens when the system shuts down, is the crawlDB is refreshed on next nutch startup?

Actually i want nutch to resume crawling where it left off in case of system shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the injection turns your flat list of seeds into entries in the crawldb. New links discovered by the parsing step are merged with the existing crawldb during the update step. Nutch won't resume crawling all by itself, if the system shutsdown you'll have to restart the Nutch scripts and the actions to take will depend on where it was when it stopped.

StormCrawler might be a better option if you need a continuous crawler that resumes itself in case of failure.

There are quite a few Nutch tutorial around which should help understand how it works, including [on from our blog](http://digitalpebble.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/index-web-with-aws-cloudsearch.html) which described both Nutch and StormCrawler.